# How to attach pageObjects to multiple browser instances in a Single test script in protractor

Tags: selenium-webdriver, protractor

I'm trying to use Page objects with multiple browser instances in a single test script.. i got a solution but i'm looking for some better solution.

### My PageObject file

```
var facebook=function(browserInstance){
browserInit=browserInstance;
element=browserInit.element;

    this.email=function(){
    return element(By.id("email"));
    }
    
    this.password=function(){
        return element(By.id("pass"));
    }
    
    this.submit=function(){
        return element(By.xpath("//input[@aria-label='Log In']"));
    }
}
module.exports=facebook;
```

### usage of Page objects with multiple browser

```
this.When(/^User entered the text in the email field$/,async function(){
// for using in browser2 i need to initialize it
        page2=new facebook(browser2);
        console.log(await page2.title()+" browser2");
        await page2.search().sendKeys("testing");
        browser2.sleep(3000);

//for using in first browser i need to initialize it
        page1=new facebook(firstBrowser);
        console.log(await page1.title()+" browser1")
        await page1.email().sendKeys(testData.Login.CM[0].Username);
        screenshots.takeScreenshot("newScreenshot");
        firstBrowser.sleep(5000);

//now if i want again in browser2.. i need to initialize the page2 with browser instance again like below
     page2=new facebook(browser2);
        console.log(await page2.title()+" browser2");
    });
```

**how to overcome this initialization every time**

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do something like this in your `conf.js` file

```
baseUrl: 'http://localhost:8081',

  onPrepare: function() {
    global.browsers = {
      a: browser,
      b: browser.forkNewDriverInstance()
    };
  }
```

And inside the spec file or the step definition file, you can have

```
this.When(/^User entered the text in the email field$/,async function(){
        let browser1 = browsers.a;
        let browser2 = browsers.b

         //do your stuff
        .
        .
        .
        .
        .
    });
```

Comment: can you please explain it with using Pageobjects... my issue is mainly using the page  objects with this multiple browser instances

Comment: i know about this `forNewDriverInstance` method and i'm looking for how to attach the browser instances to Page Object file.. as i mentioned in my question every time i need to pass the browser instance to initialize the page objects to the constructor for usage